# How to Create a Container for Each Microservice in the Same Folder

Tags: python, docker, flask, microservices

I have a project that has two microservices that need to communicate to each other through REST. For each microservice, I want to have a container in my Docker. Each one of the containers will run a Python program (microservice).

As it can be seen beneath, we have an example of how the files are organized. Suppose that `file_1.py` is one microservice and `file_2.py` is another. For each one of them, we have to start a container.

```
app
 |_ uwsgi.ini
 |_ file_1.py
 |_ file_2.py
  |_ folder_2
    |_ file_3
    |_ file_4
```

To start a container, we are using the file uwgi.ini, as it can be seen below:

```
[uwsgi]
module = file_1
callable = app
master = true
touch-reload = /app/uwsgi.ini
```

To start the container, we run the following command:

```sh
sudo docker run -d -v /app:/app -p docker_port:80 --name "container-name" "docker_name"
```

However, as it can be seen, in this way, we can only create a container for the first microservice `file_1.py`, because inside the root app, i can only have one `uwsgi.ini` in the folder. And using the command above, it will search for the `uwsgi.ini` file.

What i want to do is to have a `uwsgi.ini` for each container. I've seen that people to do it, rename `uwsgi.ini` to each container; for my case, it could be: `uwsgi_file_1.ini` and `uwsgi_file_2.ini`. But when I do that, the command to start the container doesn't find the uswsgi file, because I've changed it. Is there a way to, by typing and running the command shown before, make it search for the right `uwsgi.ini` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two easy options:

1. Make different Dockerfiles for each container and in them COPY the correct .ini file for each container to the name `uwsgi.ini`
2. Use one Dockerfile but make an entrypoint script which takes as parameter the name of the ini file name, then symlinks it before starting the actual uwsgi process.

There are probably a dozen other ways to solve this as well..

Comment: i did as instructed in 1., and worked. I found the command ENV UWSGI_INI that allows me to say which uwsgi.ini will be used to create a container to that following docker. So i created a docker for each microservice, specifing which uwsgi.ini file they would use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate Docker image for each service.  I'd suggest putting each in its own directory, and maybe even its own repository:

```
app
+-- service1
| +-- Dockerfile
| +-- uwsgi.ini
| +-- setup.cfg
| \-- app1.py
|
+-- service2
| +-- Dockerfile
| +-- uwsgi.ini
| +-- setup.cfg
| \-- app2.py
|
\-- docker-compose.yml
```

Each of the Dockerfiles can be fairly self-contained.  I put a `docker-compose.yml` file at the top level in the example, as a straightforward way to launch the services together:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./service1
    ports: ['8001:80']
  service2:
    build: ./service2
    ports: ['8002:80']
    environment:
      - SERVICE_1_URL=http://service1
```

Your proposed `docker run` command has a `-v` option that overwrites the image's `/app` directory with content from the host.  Both your suggested solution and [@vaizki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594490) then involve making some sort of Docker- or container-specific change to the file layout; the bind mount would either hide the change or cause a conflict if if you're running multiple copies of the container.  I'd recommend deleting this option (or the equivalent Compose `volumes:`); use a Python virtual environment without Docker for ordinary development.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not do that, as i am not experienced in docker, nor am I in developing. So i did what the dude before your instructed, created a docker for each microservice. But it doesn't mean i will not save your answer for later. Maybe it is the best solution, and the most sophisticated one too. 
Anyway, i thank you for your time to answer me.